# Unable to call function defined by partialmethod

Tags: python-3.x, evaluation, class-method

I'm want to use Python3 *partialmethod* and I can't call the resultant function. My code is based on the example from the Python documentation https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.4/library/functools.html

```
from functools import partialmethod
class AClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = val
    def _fun(self, x):
        z = x + self.v # some computation
        return z
    def fun(self, x):
        return partialmethod(self._fun, x)

a = AClass(10)
b = a.fun(1)
print(b()) # TypeError: 'partialmethod' object is not callable
print(a.b()) # AttributeError: 'AClass' object has no attribute 'b'
```

I understand why `a.b()` is not correct, since b is not defined in the instantiated a. The error message for `b()` does not give me enough information to understand what is going on.

How do I define a method with bound parameters and call it from outside the enclosing class? Is this possible at all, or is there a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: @Wade, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This is a good question. I would upvote that if you accepted the already suggested answer (or write why you don't accept that, if you really don't).

Answer (score 18):

I stumbled upon the same issue, and found your question. Reading about `partialmethod` more carefully, I remembered about descriptors. That is, remembered I don't really remember about descriptors. So, upon digging a bit further, here's my understanding of what is happening:

## Background

### Callables

Python functions and methods are, like anything else in python, objects. They are callable because they implement the callable protocol, that is, they implement the special method `__call__()`. You can make anything a callable this way:

```
class Igors:
    pass


igor = Igors()
try:
    igor()  # --> raises TypeError
except TypeError:
    print("Is it deaf?")

Igors.__call__ = lambda self: print("Did you call, Marster?")

igor()  # --> prints successfully
```

Prints:

```
Is it deaf?
Did you call, Marster?
```

(Note that you can't assign special methods on an instance, just on the class: [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup))

Of course you'd normally do, rather:

```
class A:
    def __call__(self):
        print("An A was called")

a = A()
a()  # prints "An A was called"
```

### Descriptors

Some useful links, but there are lots others:

- [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)
- https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/11/25/python-descriptors/

Python descriptors are objects implementing one of the `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__` methods. They are short-cutting the default attribute lookup mechanisms.

If an object has a "normal" attribute `x`, when accessing `obj.x` python looks for `x`'s value in the usual suspects: the instance's `__dict__`, the instance's class' `__dict__`, then in its base classes, and returns it.

If on the other hand an object has an attribute that is a descriptor, after looking it up, python will call the descriptor's `__get__()` with two arguments: the instance and the instance's type (the class).

**Note: the discussion is more complicated. See the linked "Descriptor HowTo Guide" for more details about `__set__` and `__delete__` and data vs. "non-data" descriptors and the order of looking them up.**

Here's another silly example:

```
class Quack:
    DEFAULT = "Quack! Quack!"

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type=None):
        print(f">>> Quacks like {obj} of type {obj_type} <<<")
        try:
            return obj.QUACK
        except AttributeError:
            return Quack.DEFAULT


class Look:
    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):
        print(f">>> Looks like {obj} <<<")
        return lambda: "a duck!"


class Duck:
    quack = Quack()
    look = Look()


class Scaup(Duck):
    """I'm a kind of a duck"""
    QUACK = "Scaup! Scaup!"


# looking up on the class
print(f"All ducks quack: {Duck.quack}\n")

# looking up on an object
a_duck = Duck()
print(f"A duck quacks like {a_duck.quack}\n")

a_scaup = Scaup()
print(f"A scaup quacks like {a_scaup.quack}\n")

# descriptor returns a callable
print(f"A duck look like {a_duck.look} ... ooops\n")
print(f"Again, a duck look() like {a_duck.look()}\n")
```

Which prints:

```
>>> Quacks like None of type <class '__main__.Duck'> <<<
All ducks quack: Quack! Quack!

>>> Quacks like <__main__.Duck object at 0x103d5bd50> of type <class '__main__.Duck'> <<<
A duck quacks like Quack! Quack!

>>> Quacks like <__main__.Scaup object at 0x103d5bc90> of type <class '__main__.Scaup'> <<<
A scaup quacks like Scaup! Scaup!

>>> Looks like <__main__.Duck object at 0x103d5bd50> <<<
A duck look like <function Look.__get__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x103d52dd0> ... ooops

>>> Looks like <__main__.Duck object at 0x103d5bd50> <<<
Again, a duck look() like a duck!
```

What you need to remember is that the magic of calling the descriptor's special methods (`__get__()` in this case) happens when python looks up the *attribute* for an `obj.attribute` lookup.

When running `a_duck.look()` python (ok, the `object.__getattribute__()` mechanism) is looking up "look" more or less as usual, obtains the value which is a descriptor (a `class Look` instance), magically calls it's `__get__()`

### partialmethod

[partialmethod()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) returns a descriptor which is *not* a callable. Instead, its `__get__()` method will return the callable, in this case an appropriate `functools.partial()` object. The partialmethod is supposed to be, similar to a method, classmethod or staticmethod, an *attribute* of an object.

Here are some ways to use partialmethod. Notice its behavior is different depending on whether you call it on a descriptor (like a method, classmethod, etc) or a non-descriptor callable. From its documentation:

> When func is a descriptor (such as a normal Python function, classmethod(), staticmethod(), abstractmethod() or another instance of partialmethod), calls to `__get__` are delegated to the underlying descriptor, and an appropriate partial object returned as the result.
>
> When func is a non-descriptor callable, an appropriate bound method is created dynamically. This behaves like a normal Python function when used as a method: the self argument will be inserted as the first positional argument, even before the args and keywords supplied to the partialmethod constructor.

```
from functools import partialmethod


class Counter:
    def __init__(self, initial):
        self._value = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._value)

    def increase(self, by):
        self._value += by

    # on descriptor (a method is a descriptor too, that is doing the "self" magic)
    increment = partialmethod(increase, 1)

    # on non-descriptor
    name = lambda self: f"Counter of {self}"
    increment2 = partialmethod(name)

    # partialmethod generator

    def increment_returner(self, by):
        return partialmethod(Counter.increase, by)


# partialmethod used as intended on methods:

c = Counter(0)
c.increment()
print(f"incremented counter: {c}")    # --> 1
print(f"c.increment: {c.increment}")  # --> functools.partial(<bound method Counter.increase of <__main__.Counter object at 0x108fa0610>>, 1)
print(f"c.increment has __call__: {hasattr(c.increment, '__call__')}")  # --> True

print()

# partialmethod used (as intended?), on non-descriptor callables
print(f"c.name() returns: {c.name()}")  # --> "Counter of 1"
print(f"c.name is: {c.name}")  # --> <bound method Counter.<lambda> of <__main__.Counter object at 0x10208dc10>>

print()

# a "partialmethod" generator

incrementer = c.increment_returner(2)
print(f"icrementer: {incrementer}")  # --> functools.partialmethod(<bound method Counter.increase of <__main__.Counter object at 0x104e74790>>, 2, )
print(f"incrementer has __call__: {hasattr(incrementer, '__call__')}")  # --> False
print(f"incrementer has __get__: {hasattr(incrementer, '__get__')}")  # --> True

incrementer.__get__(c, Counter)()
print(f"counter after 'simulating' python's magic: {c}")  # --> 3
print(f"'simulated' invocation of attribute lookup: {incrementer.__get__(c, Counter)}")  # --> functools.partial(<bound method Counter.increase of <__main__.Counter object at 0x10d7b7c50>>, 2)
```

And the output:

```
incremented counter: 1
c.increment: functools.partial(<bound method Counter.increase of <__main__.Counter object at 0x101fffb10>>, 1)
c.increment has __call__: True

c.name() returns: Counter of 1
c.name is: <bound method Counter.<lambda> of <__main__.Counter object at 0x101fffb10>>

icrementer: functools.partialmethod(<function Counter.increase at 0x102008050>, 2, )
incrementer has __call__: False
incrementer has __get__: True
counter after 'simulating' python's magic: 3
'simulated' invocation of attribute lookup: functools.partial(<bound method Counter.increase of <__main__.Counter object at 0x101fffb10>>, 2)
```

## Answers

In your example, `b()` doesn't work because:

1. `partialmethod` returns a descriptor whose `__get__()` would return a properly crafted callable, a partial object working like a bound method ("injecting" self).
2. Even if you'd call `b.__get__(a, AClass)()` this would fail because `self._fun` is already a bound to `self` and so you get `TypeError: _fun() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. If I'm not mistaken, `self` is injected twice.

As I understand your question, you want to be able to *generate* methods with bound parameters. I guess you could do something like:

```
from functools import partial, partialmethod


class AClass():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.v = val

    def _fun(self, x):
        z = x + self.v  # some computation
        return z

    def fun1(self, x):
        def bound_fun_caller():
            return self._fun(x)
        return bound_fun_caller

    def fun2(self, x):
        # quite silly, but here it is
        return partialmethod(AClass._fun, x).__get__(self, AClass)

    def fun3(self, x):
        return partial(AClass._fun, self, x)

    # for completeness, binding to a known value
    plus_four = partialmethod(_fun, 4)

    def add_fun(self, name, x):
        # Careful, this might hurt a lot...
        setattr(AClass, name, partialmethod(AClass._fun, x))


a = AClass(10)

b1 = a.fun1(1)
print(b1())

b2 = a.fun2(2)
print(b2())

b3 = a.fun3(3)
print(b3())

print(a.plus_four())

a.add_fun("b5", 5)
print(a.b5())
```

Comment: This is a surprisingly well-researched answer. Thanks!